# Is there a common name for ailerons, elevators and rudder?

Tags: aircraft-design, terminology, aircraft-structures

Since ailerons, elevators and rudder are all designed in a similar way, that is, they are attached to a fixed structure from where they move in both direction on that particular axis.

For example on a typical aircraft:

- Elevator: On the horizontal stabilizer, moves Up and Down.
- Aileron: On the wing, moves Up and Down oppositely
- Rudder: On the vertical stabilizer, moves Left and Right

Is there a name in common we can call all of them?

Like in aircraft design/structure can we say that they are all X kind of thing?

[image: Aircraft structures]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*Primary control surfaces* is the typical name for ailerons, elevators, rudders, etc. *Auxiliary flight controls* include things like flaps, slats, slots, spoilers, leading edge devices, etc. *Secondary flight controls* are the same as AUX flight controls, just a different name.

Comment: "*ailerons, elevator, rudder, **etc.***" - what else is there?

Comment: It makes me think of elevons, wing warping, and stabilators. You could also count hybrids such as flaperons.

Comment: @Bergi canards?

Comment: Just to make sure, trimmable horizontal stabilizer would be a secondary control surface? It's not really primary, but at the same time, for pitch control, it's usually the only thing the AP would use, so for AP it's really primary...

Comment: @bergi The B-2 has control surfaces called elevons, so that would be another example. It also has a GLAS (Gust Load Alleviation System) which probably counts as a primary control surface

Comment: Trim is an interesting one.  It would be possible that you could lose control of say the elevator (snapped cable), but continue to maintain positive pitch control with the trim.  It would not be as responsive or accurate but it would beat the alternative.  On transatlantic / transpacific flights in the P-3 when the autopilot wasn't working (which was most of the time) I flew with the elevator trim.  It was a manual wheel vs electric so fine tuning with it was very easy.

Comment: @EarlGrey A canard typically has elevators. So the canard itself, like a horizontal stabilizer, isn't a control surface in such a case.

Comment: @HangarRash I do not think we can say anything "typical" about canards. See *your* canards (i.e. https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-saab-37-viggen-thunderbolt-swedish-single-engine-short-medium-range-58657571.html ) and *my* canards ( https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-cac94e6500918b03d24676e1a9128a87 )
ps: I owe no rights on the here linked pictures, I will remove the links soon.

Comment: @EarlGrey Admittedly I was thinking primarily of canards like those seen on Rutan derived aircraft (Long-EZ, Cozy, Velocity, etc.) and not the type where the whole canard is a "little" rotating surface.

Comment: @Bergi collective, tilt...

Answer (score 12):

All of the aileron, rudder, and elevator surfaces may be considered "aerodynamic control surfaces." This would also cover the primary, secondary, and auxiliary control surfaces, as noted by Wyatt.

Comment: Or even just "control surfaces".